# Invoking getters of a generic enum

Tags: java, reflection, enums, invoke

I need to invoke the field accessor methods, i.e the getter of a generic enum, but cannot figure out how to invoke the methods, or more specifically how to pass a generic enum as a parameter for the invoke-method.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

this is what I'd like to do more or less.

```
public void(Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType) {
    Enum<?>[] enumConstants = enumType.getEnumConstants();
    String[] text = new String[enumConstants.length];
    String[] names =  new String[enumConstants.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < enumConstants.length; i++ ) {
        Method[] methods = enumConstants[i].getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m: enumConstants[i].getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println(enumConstants[i].name() + ": " + m.getName() + "()");
            try {
                if (GET_KEY_METHOD_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(m.getName())) {
                    Object value = m.invoke(I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE, "");
                    System.out.println(value.toString());
                }
                if (GET_VALUE_METHOD_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(m.getName())) {
                    Object value = m.invoke(I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE, "");
                    System.out.println(value.toString());
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the obvious first guess is `m.invoke(enumConstants[i])`, withotu any `""` since a getter should not have any parameters. Does that fail? If so, what does the error message say?

Comment: Have you tried to put enumConstants[i] on "I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE"?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters for the [`Method.invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) method are always the instance the method is called for, followed by the list of parameters.

```
Object value = m.invoke(enumConstants[i]);
```

is most likely what you need.

Also you should add a type parameter to the method:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> void myMethod(Class<T> enumType) {
    T[] enumConstants = enumType.getEnumConstants();
```

BTW: Have you considered using a `interface` containing those methods? This would allow you to access the methods without having to use reflection.

Also take a look at the [`getDeclaredMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) method and keep in mind that enum constants may instances of a subclass of the enum class, so you should use the methods not containing `Declared`. Also find the methods for the enum class, not for the individual classes for less lookups:

For example consider the following:

```
public enum MyEnum implements M1M2Interface {
    ONE() {

        @Override
        public String m1(String s) {
            return "1";
        }

    }, TWO() {

        @Override
        public int m2(BigInteger i) {
            return 2;
        }

    }
    ;

}

public interface M1M2Interface {
    default String m1(String s) {
        return "2";
    }

    default int m2(BigInteger i) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> void testEnum(Class<T> enumType) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    T[] enumConstants = enumType.getEnumConstants();
    Method m1 = enumType.getMethod("m1", String.class);
    Method m2 = enumType.getMethod("m2", BigInteger.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < enumConstants.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(enumConstants[i].name() + ":");
        try {
            System.out.println("    m1:" + m1.invoke(enumConstants[i], "Hello World"));
            System.out.println("    m2:" + m2.invoke(enumConstants[i], (BigInteger) null));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`getDeclaredMethod` wouldn't work here, since the methods could be declared/implemented by:

- The interface (declared only prior to java 8)
- the enum class
- the enum constant (if there is no declaration at a "higher level" the method cannot be accessed using `EnumName.CONSTANT_NAME.methodName()` so it's unlikely to be done...)

Comment: That did the job in the first place. Tanks thousandfold. Yes I was considering to use an interface, but somehow the architecture of this fairly old application I'm working on prevents me to do this... maybe some tiime though.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is rarely the correct answer to anything.  Consider having your enum classes implement a common interface, like [StandardCopyOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html) and [Month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) do.

If you can't modify the enum classes, and if you're using Java 8, you can pass the getter method as an argument:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> E findMatch(Class<E> enumClass,
                                       Function<E, String> nameGetter,
                                       Predicate<String> matcher) {
    for (E value : EnumSet.allOf(enumClass)) {
        String name = nameGetter.apply(value);
        if (matcher.test(name)) {
            return value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static enum Season {
    SPRING("Spr"),
    SUMMER("Sum"),
    FALL("Fal"),
    WINTER("Win");

    private final String abbreviation;

    private Season(String abbrev) {
        this.abbreviation = abbrev;
    }

    public getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }
}

public void doStuff() {
    // ...

    String abbrToFind = "Sum";
    Season match = findMatch(Season.class,
        Season::getAbbreviation,
        Predicate.isEqual(abbrToFind));
}
```

If you're using a version older than Java 8, you can still do the same thing, but you'll need to define and implement the interfaces yourself:

```
public interface Function<A, B> {
    B apply(A input);
}

public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T value);
}

public void doStuff() {
    // ...

    final String abbrToFind = "Sum";
    Season match = findMatch(Season.class,
        new Function<Season, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Season season) {
                return season.getAbbreviation(),
            }
        },
        new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(String name) {
                return Objects.equals(name, abbrToFind);
            }
        });
}
```